# How can I plug my in-line stand-alone microphone, into my laptop that has no more 3.5 mm audio jacks?

Tags: microphone

1. My dad's patients complain that they can't hear him clearly when he uses his laptop's built-in microphone, which produces echoes and makes him sound like he's underwater. Dad's [Lenovo](http://www.notebookreview.com/notebookreview/lenovo-ideapad-y700-review-a-balanced-behemoth/) proffers just 1 3.5mm audio jack — see my green arrows below. But he already plugged his external speakers into it! Don't ask him to unplug his external speakers, because he needs them to hear patients clearly. His built-in speakers are too shoddy.

[image]

[image]

2. Then how can he plug in his [Zalman ZM-MIC1](https://www.zalman.com/EN/Product/ProductDetail.do?pageIndex=1&pageSize=10&productSeq=894&searchCategory1=0&searchCategory2=-99&searchCategory3=-99&searchKey=&searchWord=zm-mic1)? He found least 5 stand-alone in-line microphones in our attic. Please don't instruct us to waste money and buy new microphones.

[image]

Comment: What about a simple USB-to-Audio jack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see in the image that the audio jack supports both speakers and mics given it's a headphone with mic picture.

So you could buy an adapter that will receive the mic and the speakers and transform it to a "three line" male 3.5mm audio jack.

Luckily, such things... [EXIST!](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01I3A47I4)

[image: adapter]

There are other [adapters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IRVQ0F8) that will let you connect the speakers and the microphone to a USB port:

[image]

Finally there are audio jack to USB adapters for only one jack:

[image]

Sadly, there is no way to do it without some type of adapter (either the one that uses the jack or the one that uses a USB port), even if you DIY, you'd still need to buy the parts.